# apk creation file MainActivity

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

to make an app for the play store you have to change the name of the package in the file MainActuivity but my file is still in the directory ktolin/com/example/lectureimg

```
package com.example.lectureimg

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
}
```

replace

```
package remy.andCo.lectureimg

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
```

}

is it a problem?
and how to do to not have this tree structure or to have a tree structure that looks like the one of the package

thanks cdl remy

Comment: Kotlin doesn't care about directory structure matching the package name, so it should be fine. But the package you actually need to change for the Play Store should be the one in the manifest. The package your Activity class is in can be anything. However, I don't use Flutter so I don't know if there are other considerations.

Comment: thank you for your answer
but to have a structure which corresponds it is enough,
in android, create a project with from the beginning
the good structure of directory then to move all the file has the hand

that will make a stage of less to create an apk and will be useful for the next project